# How to replace deprecated functions from my wordpress code?

Tags: wordpress, deprecated

The function `get_all_category_ids()` from WordPress it is deprecated so I need to replace with `get_terms()` but I can't make it work. Can you please help me to make this code to be valid on WordPress 4.0 ?

```
<label>Choose category</label>
<select name="mycategories" >';

$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
foreach($category_ids as $cat_id)
{
    $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);

    if($category == $cat_id)
    {
        $html .= '<option selected="selected" value="'.$cat_id.'" '.$cat_name.'>'.$cat_name.'</option>';
    } else {
        $html .= '<option value="'.$cat_id.'" '.$cat_name.'>'.$cat_name.'</option>';
    }
}
$html.= '</select>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried with `get_terms()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get all post categories ordered by count.**

*String syntax:*

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
```

*Array syntax:*

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
 ) );
```

*Get all the links categories:*

```
$mylinks_categories = get_terms( 'link_category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
```

See the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).